# SSIS Deployment Utility - specifying different folders in MSDB

Tags: sql-server-2005, deployment, visual-studio-2005, ssis

I am deploying my SSIS packages to MSDB by configuring the deployment utility and creating the manifest file in Visual Studio (2005).

In the Integration Services, I created a new folder to segregate my packages. Is there a way to specify this folder for my packages when creating the deployment utility?

If not, how do I move packages into the new folder once they're installed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the target folder in the deployment utility, as it can be used for both MSDB and file system deployments. It would be something you specified in the deployment wizard after selecting a SQL Server deployment - but the option isn't presented.

Once deployed, you can move packages around using the dtutil.exe utility, using the /move subcommand

```
dtutil /Sources *serverName* /SQL *packageName* /move SQL;*folderName\packageName*
```

As you can also use it to copy packages between the file system and MSDB storage, DTutil offers an alternative method of deploying files in the first place.